# No such module 'UIKit'

Tags: xcode, macos, wkwebview

All I want to do is make the most basic macOS / OS X app that just shows a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)...

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}}
```

But this shows the error:

> No such module 'UIKit'

Answer (score 51, accepted):

UIKit is for mobile apps, not MacOS apps. You want AppKit.

Comment: Okay. So how do I create a simple WKWebView for my mac app... not for iOS. The code above is clearly for iOS I guess.

Comment: Delete the `import UIKit` and import AppKit & Cocoa.

Comment: Now I have 6 errors... including "Use of undeclared type 'UIViewController'"

Comment: `UIViewController` is part of `UIKit`. You can't use any UIKit class. In this case  `UIViewController`'s counterpart in AppKit is `NSViewController`

Comment: I have a mobile app. I'm getting this for a pod.

Answer (score 3):

- First of all your detail shows that you are working on **MacOS** app, but your Tittle is about **UIKit**.
- **APPKit** MacOS development and **UIKit** is for iOS/TabOS.

1. **UIKit** cannot be import for **MacOS** playground environment. Use **AppKit**
2. If you are developing for iOS mobile environment and still face issue importing **UIKit** then you can follow following steps:

If you already selected **iOS** while creating Playground file
but still getting error **No such module 'UIKit'**, then follow following steps.
Xcode 13
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l5Kb.png)

[image]

[image: Step By Step Action]

Comment: The question is about building a macOS app, not an iOS app. The error is caused by trying to import UIKit instead of AppKit.

Answer (score 2):

- Open utilities from the top right corner
- Change the platform to IOS

Then it should be okay to use UIKit

Comment: A helpful screenshot in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49971034/446106 illustrates how to change the platform.  Make sure Inspectors (the right-hand sidebar) is open.

Comment: The question is about building a macOS app, not an iOS app. The error is caused by trying to import UIKit instead of AppKit.

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'show utilities' window.  If the platform is set to MacOS, you'll get this error if you're calling UIKit.  Same thing goes if your wanting IoS and your calling AppKit.

```
http://iosbrain.com/blog/2018/08/16/xcode-9-playground-error-no-such-module-uikit-or-appkit/
```

Answer (score -1):

Check what device you are using. If you are using macOS instead of an iPhone 14, you will get this fault when you import UIKit. You do not have to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: This duplicates essentially every other answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute. You can show your support for an answer by upvoting.

Comment: My software does not show the dialog screen like the one in the screenshot. So I posted to how I made it work with my version. Or it is available but I could not find it. Sorry this year one for me.